# How do I switch to a backup database in Django when the primary is down?

Tags: mysql, database, django

I have read the Django MultiDB documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/multi-db/ and googled for a while and still could not come up with a solution.

Situation: There is a Django application and a MySQL database for it. The database is set up on two servers with master-master replication. The Django application is configured to read from both of them using a modified slave-master example from Django docs. Both reads and writes work fine and randomly go to both databases.

Problem: Server1 goes down. Now half of the database requests fail.

How can I configure Django and/or MySQL in such a way that Django would continue to work fully in case of a failure of one MySQL server?

Comment: Look at this code https://github.com/isagalaev/django_replicated/blob/master/django_replicated/router.py

Answer (score 0):

Use a mysql proxy like [mysql-proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/). You can do load-balancing and automatic failover using it.

Answer (score 0):

While mysql-proxy may be good use, this all depends on your site.

IS this a production quality, revenue generating site? If so I would suggest an actual Load Balancer that balances the load appropriately. Then if one server goes down, all connections will be sent to the one live DB server.

The reason why I say mysql-proxy should NOT be used, is that its an alpha product and should not be used in a revenue generating, production role.

Answer (score 0):

HAProxy is a production grade solution that could be used for this. Balancing or automatic failover of MySQL pairs is fraught with gotchas, do check you are partitioning your auto increments etc!

Answer (score 0):

Have 2 separate settings files with first one connecting to the master 1 and second one connecting to master 2 . Then load the setting files in an if loop and have a catch exception should first one fail to connect to the master 1 setting file then use the second settings file to master 2 . This way you are also letting the master to master do the replication rather than you writing you both databases at an application layer